# Safe execution of untrusted Haskell code

Tags: haskell, execution, isolation, sandbox

I'm looking for a way to run an arbitrary Haskell code safely (or refuse to run unsafe code).

Must have:

- module/function whitelist
- timeout on execution
- memory usage restriction

Capabilities I would *like* to see:

- ability to kill thread
- compiling the modules to native code
- caching of compiled code
- running several interpreters concurrently
- complex datatype for compiler errors (insted of simple message in String)

With that sort of functionality it would be possible to implement a browser plugin capable of running arbitrary Haskell code, which is the idea I have in mind.

**EDIT:** I've got two answers, both great. Thanks! The sad part is that there doesn't seem to be ready-to-go library, just a similar program. It's a useful resource though. Anyway I think I'll wait for 7.2.1 to be released and try to use SafeHaskell in my own program.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We've been doing this for about 8 years now in [lambdabot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot), which supports:

- a controlled namespace
- OS-enforced timeouts
- native code modules
- caching
- concurrent interactive top-levels
- custom error message returns.

This series of rules is documented, see:

- **[Safely running untrusted Haskell code](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Safely_running_untrusted_Haskell_code)**
- **[mueval](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mueval)**, an alternative implementation based on ghc-api

The approach to safety taken in lambdabot inspired the [Safe Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SafeHaskell) language extension work.

---

For approaches to dynamic extension of compiled Haskell applications, in Haskell, see the two papers:

- [Dynamic Extension of Typed Functional Languages](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/papers/dons-phd-thesis.pdf), and
- [Dynamic applications from the ground up](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/papers/yi.pdf).

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because more people voted on this one. Simon's answer is great too. Thank you for responses!

Answer (score 26):

GHC 7.2.1 will likely have a new facility called [SafeHaskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SafeHaskell) which covers some of what you want.  SafeHaskell ensures type-safety (so things like `unsafePerformIO` are outlawed), and establishes a trust mechanism, so that a library with a safe API but implemented using unsafe features can be trusted.  It is designed exactly for running untrusted code.

For the other practical aspects (timeouts and so on), lambdabot as Don says would be a great place to look.

Comment: What part of SafeHaskell proposal will be implemented in 7.2.1? The whole thing?

Comment: David Terei has implemented the compiler parts of SafeHaskell, the patch is waiting in my review queue.  The rest is modifying the base package and the other libraries to use Safe and Trustworthy as appropriate.  David is working on that part right now.  I expect SafeHaskell will be available in some experimental state in 7.2.1.